# Why is Java.Lang.Math not abstract?

Tags: java, abstract-class

The "abstract" keyword means you cannot create an instance of the class (an object).

Java.Lang.Math is preceded with the following keywords

```
public final class Math {
...
}
```

But no "abstract" keyword. The class simply provides a collection of related *static* variables and methods, like PI and sin().

Static means that those variables/methods can't be unique between different instances of the object (there is only one copy of those variables/methods associated with the class itself). So why even allow the programmer to create an instance of the class? Why not precede with "abstract"?

Comment: You should also note that it has a private constructor so nobody can create it anyways.

Comment: `abstract` means you can't create an instance, but you could override and THEN create instances. You create instances of `List` when you declare `new LinkedList()` even though `List` is abstract. `final` means it can't be overridden.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`java.lang.Math` is a Utility class (contains only static utility methods).

Correct way to define utility class is to make it **final** so that no other class can extend it and to have **private no-args constructor** so that no one can create an instance of the class.

So you won't be able to create instance of class any how. However if you go by **abstract** approach, you cannot use **final** and there is no way you can prevent it from being extended. Hence former approach is better.

Comment: I chose this as the solution, because it succinctly combines Braj's and KarolS's answers, and I like that you called it a "Utility" class which exposes the intent that the class should neither be instantiated nor extended, but just used as is.

Answer (score 14):

`final` and `abstract` keywords can't be applied together because `final` class can't be overridden and `abstract` classes are meant for override.

> A class that is declared `final` cannot be `subclassed` that is used for creating an [`immutable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) class such as String

It's better explained under [JSL section - 8.1.1. Class Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)

1. An `abstract` class is a class that is incomplete, or to be considered incomplete.
2. A class can be declared `final` if its definition is complete and no subclasses are desired or required.

both above statements are *contradicting* each-other.

---

If you want to read more about then have a look at *Java Tutroial* on [A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)

1. Don't provide "setter" methods — methods that modify fields or objects referred to by fields.
2. Make all fields final and private.
3. Don't allow subclasses to override methods. The simplest way to do this is to declare `the class as final`. A more sophisticated approach is to make `the constructor private` and construct instances in `factory methods`.
4. If the instance fields include references to mutable objects, don't allow those objects to be changed:

   - Don't provide methods that modify the mutable objects.
   - Don't share references to the mutable objects.

Comment: Gotchya. I assume you mean "extended" by "overridden" (although I suppose they are interchangeable). At first it made no sense to me that final and abstract should be mutually exclusive, because what if you wanted a class that could neither be extended nor instantiated. I thought this situation would require both keywords, but @KarolS 's answer made me realize that you can achieve this effect by using the final keyword and then making your constructor private!

Comment: "*...because `final` class can't be overridden*" you probably meant *extended* (overriding applies to methods, not classes).

Comment: I don't think so that you need both keywords where the purpose of both the keywords are just opposite. `final` full-fill the requirement if all the methods are complete and there is no chance to override it in future.

Answer (score 8):

If it were abstract, someone could do

```
public class NewMath extends Math {
```

which frankly speaking makes no sense.

However, you cannot create a new Math instance anyway because its only constructor is private:

```
private Math() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`final` means you cannot extend it, the reason you cannot create an instance is because the constructor is private.  This is how (in java) you define static classes or factory classes.

Answer (score 0):

The Abstract keyword means the class can't be Instantiable but it can be Extended.
And in case of Utility Classes such Math Class,Extending it has no sense. Declaring the no-args Constructor makes it Non-Instantiable and final makes it non-Extendable...So its the Perfect Match .... And If you use Abstract then you can't use Final...

Comment: You just repeat the words of the other answers .. so how is this post helpful?